# To create expandable table view in IOS 5.0

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, expand

How to create expandable tableview in IOS 5.0.if anyone knows help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Try: https://github.com/jonasman/JNExpandableTableView

Comment: here is the easiest way to create it using swift https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKeVv0I3jnA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shows you how to expand/collapse Table View Sections http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/

Comment: Thanks james for your quick reply

Comment: No problem hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

JKExpandTableView is an open source library implementing an expandable table view (subclass of UITableView) .  Please sure to checkout the provided sample project as well. :
http://jackkwok.github.io/JKExpandTableView/

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SubTable](https://github.com/ajkoshy7/SubTable), it handles the expanding/collapsing for you, and it's easy to plug in and start customizing