# Change height of static UITableView in runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need change height of my UITable in runtime, when I change height of my cells.

My tableView is static and cann't scrolling

[image]

I change height of my tableView in next method (It is very bad decision on my opinion, so that  I ask you to help):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        self.tableView.originY = 95;
        self.tableView.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height + 2;
        self.tableViewBottom.originY = tableView.originY + tableView.height + 15;
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.width, self.tableViewBottom.originY + self.tableViewBottom.height + 10);
    }
}
```

Problem with `self.tableView` where clls may change there size. `self.tableViewBottom` second tableView and lay under the first.

So I have next:

[image]

And when clicked:

[image]

Sometimes tableView change there position on `y` after clicking (you can see that size from image is more that in first case) So I thought that first string in code may help: `self.tableView.originY = 95;`

[image]

And why if I make in storyboard height of 100

[image]

My tableView  show only one cell, so height of tableView don't change programmatically;

[image]

**EDIT**
No one of answer cann\t help me, it\s all about change of height of cell. I think I need update height of uitableview after all cells is displaying. How Can I do it?

Comment: Try this project  https://github.com/HQinNUS/ExpandingTableExample

Comment: Is autolayout enabled in your xib or storyboard?  [Here's how to check.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13201690/77567)

Comment: hi try this and let me know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345601/to-create-expandable-table-view-in-ios-5-0/14150973#14150973

Comment: y not using dynamic cells??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981071/dynamic-height-for-static-table-cells-with-wrapping-labels

Comment: @rob mayoff, I need write for iOS 5, so I cann\t use autolayouts