# How to open a new tableview when selecting a row

Tags: ios, row, tableview

I have a UITableview and for every row I tap, another UITableview must be opened. At this moment I've already created a UITableview and added elements and tap gesture recognition to it, but I still don't know how to open another view for every row I tap.

BTW: I'm using storyboards.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There are many tutorials online that can help you through this issue. *Unfortunately*, this is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific. Do you want to "open" a new `UITableView` "below" the tapped row (like nested `UITableViews`) or move to another UIViewController with other UITableView.
If you want to achieve the latter thing simply use  `UINavigationViewController's pushViewController` in
 `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` `UITableViewDelegate` method.

In order to achieve the latter effect you'd have to implement the more complicated behavior with far more complicated code but luckily we were given a few amazing open source libraries by fellow developers (for example SDNestedTable). If you use them don't forget to follow rules specified in the license.

Comment: I'm trying to make a to-do List, for example the main list shows the days of the week and for every day must be a certain number of tasks to complete. In the main view i've already added the days of the week and also every the tap recognition event (by now it only prints in console wthat row has been tapped). The next step is to implement how to open a new table view for the tasks of the day.

Comment: Okay, it is a very easy task. Please learn the basics of iOS dev before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

use:

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

in the tableView's delegate and then you can either use

`[self performSegueForIdentifer:storyboardSegueIdentifier];`

if you setup a storyboard segue to move to another view depending on what row was selected or present another view modally with

`[self presentViewController]`.

or if you are using a navigation controller you can do

`[[self navigationController] popToViewController:viewControllerToShow];`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to have a expandable/ collapsable table view effect, you can see the below link [To create expandable table view in IOS 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345601/to-create-expandable-table-view-in-ios-5-0) 
or http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html

If you wish to have a normal navigation on tap of a cell, then it is probably simple. All you have to do is to push a new controller in the current controller. I would suggest you go thru this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html